# rosbag fix does not like rule produced by rosbag check

Tags: ros-fuerte, ubuntu-precise, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use **rosbag fix** to migrate some of the messages contained in one of my bag files since I converted one of my data types (`asctec_hl/IMURaw`) to a new one (`asctec_msgs/IMUData`).

I followed the [Alternative Approach to Making Rules](http://ros.org/wiki/rosbag/migration#Alternative_Approach_to_Making_Rules) and did the following:

```
$ rosbag check in.bag -g myrules.bmr
The following migrations need to occur:
 * From: asctec_hl/IMURaw [f977ecf9dfe66d1c7d6ade693ec96195]
   To:   Unknown
    1 rules missing:
     * From: asctec_hl/IMURaw [f977ecf9dfe66d1c7d6ade693ec96195]
       To:   Unknown
The message type asctec_hl/IMURaw appears to have moved.  Please enter the type to migrate
it to.
>asctec_msgs/IMUData
Creating the migration rule for asctec_msgs/IMUData requires additional missing rules:

The necessary rule files have been written to: myrules.bmr
```

As explained in the docs I inspected the produced rule, modified it and set `valid = True`.

When trying to actually fix the bag with the produced rule I get:

```
$ rosbag fix in.bag out.bag myrules.bmr
Bag could not be migrated.  The following migrations could not be performed:
 * From: asctec_hl/IMURaw [f977ecf9dfe66d1c7d6ade693ec96195]
   To:   Unknown
    1 rules missing:
     * From: asctec_msgs/IMUData [4431bfb48b28d4830885ef905ffa3a5c]
       To:   Unknown
Try running 'rosbag check' to create the necessary rule files or run 'rosbag fix' with the
'--force' option.
```

Any suggestion about what might be wrong given that [`myrules.bmr`](https://www.dropbox.com/s/02fvhja402eyxf0/myrules.bmr) specifies exactly the rule that `rosbag fix` claims is missing?

BTW: I am using fuerte (latest Ubuntu 12.04 binaries) and both of the packages in question (which belong to different stacks) are built using rosmake.

Submitted as ticket [4016](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/4016)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39386/rosbag-fix-does-not-like-rule-produced-by-rosbag-check/) by [renzodenardi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2291/renzodenardi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-07-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arrakis](https://answers.ros.org/users/2996/arrakis/) on 2013-11-05**:
As far as I can tell, this functionality still seems to be broken over a year later, rendering rosbag migration totally unusable in its most common use case.  Which is nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a bug in the bag migration. I can't tell for sure.

Perhaps you should open a Trac ticket for it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1